# MongoDB sharded cluster : using a query option for mongoexport utility and mongo version V5.0.6

Tags: mongodb, utility, mongoexport

Using Windows 10 home CMD:

> mongoexport --uri="mongodb+srv://cluster0.80g0y.mongodb.net/reporting" --username=quser --authenticationDatabase=admin --password=sample123  --collection=pReports    --query "{'index':3}" --out=personsatlas.json

I tried in most of the ways as document suggested, still not able to execute it right. So need input on the query option. My mongo --version is 5.0.6.

I tried
--query "{'index':3}",
--query '{"index":3}'
with equal to sign in between and without .

errors are

1. Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input with --query "{'index':3}"
2. query '[39 123 105 110 100 101 120 58 51 125 39]' is not valid JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}; with --query='{"index":3}'

===
C:\Users>mongoexport --version
mongoexport version: 100.5.2
git version: e2842eb549308c16e070fb2e197d4631cfd085cb
Go version: go1.16.7
os: windows
arch: amd64
compiler: gc

Comment: Seems you forgot the "=" after --query. From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/#std-option-mongoexport.--query), it looks like the query needs to be surrounded by single quotes and values inside are double-quoted.

Comment: error is :                                                                                                                            
 --query='{"index":3}' 
2022-02-16T17:21:03.546-0500    query '[39 123 105 110 100 101 120 58 51 125 39]' is not valid JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}                                                                                                                  Using Windows 10 home CMD